# Custom If statement in SSRS from crystal

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I am trying to convert the following code from crystal reports custom code to work in SSRS. 
How could I implement this in custom code / an IIF expression to work in SSRS?

```
if {rptSurveyDetail;1.QT1} = 0 then
    if {rptSurveyDetail;1.Question1} = 0 then "No" 
        else if {rptSurveyDetail;1.Question1} = 1 then "Yes" else ""
else if {rptSurveyDetail;1.QT1} = 1 or {rptSurveyDetail;1.QT1} = 7 then
    ToText({rptSurveyDetail;1.Question1},0,"") 
else if {rptSurveyDetail;1.QT1} = 2 then
    ToText({rptSurveyDetail;1.Question1},{rptSurveyDetail;1.QP1},"")
else ""
```

Here is the IIF statement that is failing at the moment... it is only showing the QT1 Values of 1, 2, and 3...

```
=IIF(Fields!QT1.Value = 0, IIF(Fields!Question1.Value = 0, "No", IIF(Fields!Question1.Value = 1, "Yes", "")), IIF(Fields!QT1.Value = 1 or Fields!QT1.Value = 7, Fields!Question1.Value, IIF(Fields!QT1.Value = 2, Fields!Question1.Value & "," & Fields!QP1.Value, "")))
```

The custom code I was using was coming up with syntax errors, so a solution for custom code of IIF will do just fine!

Answer (score 1):

I used parameters for testing and you will need to change to the fields from your dataset.

```
=IIf(Parameters!QT1.Value=0 And Parameters!Question1.Value=0, "No", IIf(Parameters!QT1.Value=0 And Parameters!Question1.Value=1, "Yes", IIf(Parameters!QT1.Value=1 Or Parameters!QT1.Value=7, CStr(Parameters!Question1.Value), IIf(Parameters!QT1.Value=2,CStr(Parameters!Question1.Value) & "," & CStr(Parameters!QP1.Value),"")))  )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is NO parameter from the formula above. All the fields there are from stored procedures.

You may check the false part in your conversion. In Crystal, the false part can be left out, but in SSRS, any condition must have both true part and the false part.

Most Crystal Reports can be perfectly converted by automatic conversion. You may check Crystal Migration Services.